# Open WebView with webpage related to post in Android using Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, webview, firebase-realtime-database, android-webview

I have an activity like below, what I want is that when I click on the text it **opens a webView** and the detailed info of this post is shown there through a webpage.I have implemented **Firebase database** for webPage retrieval but it did not work the app gets crashed evertime I click on it. I have searched many questions but did not get any useful answer for my case, please help.

> I am using Android Studio and Firebase

**Activity screenshot**

[image]

**webView java file:**

```
   public class webViewNews extends AppCompatActivity {
private WebView webviewthis;
private RecyclerView webVieRes;
private DatabaseReference mdataRef;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview_page);
    webVieRes = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.resycleWeb);
    mdataRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("webing");
    webviewthis = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView_news);

        webviewthis.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webviewthis.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webviewthis.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    }

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<post2web,post2webViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapte = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<post2web,post2webViewHolder>(

            post2web.class,
            R.layout.web_card,
            post2webViewHolder.class,
            mdataRef
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(post2webViewHolder viewHolder, post2web model, int position) {
            viewHolder.setWebViewPost(model.getWebViewPost());
        }
    };
    webVieRes.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapte);
}

public static class post2webViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    View mView;

    public post2webViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
    }

    public void setWebViewPost(String webViewPost) {
        WebView post_web = (WebView) mView.findViewById(R.id.webView_news);
        post_web.loadUrl(webViewPost);
    }
}
}
```

**webView xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
    android:id="@+id/resycleWeb">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

**WebView CardView layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webView_news"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**Crash Log:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{andromeda.petrochemical/andromeda.petrochemical.webViewNews}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.webkit.WebView.setWebViewClient(android.webkit.WebViewClient)' on a null object reference
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.webkit.WebView.setWebViewClient(android.webkit.WebViewClient)' on a null object reference
                                                                                at andromeda.petrochemical.webViewNews.onCreate(webViewNews.java:33)
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Comment: Hey, please provide the logcat for your crash. Thanks

Comment: @SachinAggarwal added the log crash report sir and it is showing nullpoint exception but i have added the webView in the code,i dont know why it is coming

Answer (score 0):

Since `webviewthis` is `null`, it means that `findViewById()` must be returning `null` in following line -

```
webviewthis = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView_news);
```

This is because your `R.layout.webview_page` does not contain any view with the id `webView_news`.

I guess this helps you. Thanks

**NOTE -**

I am not sure what you are trying to do, but if you want to have `CardView` with `RecyclerView`, first add your `CardView` to `RecyclerView` dynamically and then use -

`webVieRes.findViewById(R.id.webView_news)`

i.e. It is important to use view.findViewById(), not Activity.findViewById().

Comment: Tell me if this doesn't work for you !! Thanks @RohitB

Comment: sorry for late reply sir, but can you please tell me what you mean by adding cardview to recyclerView dynamicaly.

Comment: You can follow this tutorial to learn how to add card view in recyclerview dynamically. https://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-card-view-and-recycler-view/